# Writing a regex expression for special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know my code is wrong,  I am trying to test for certain characters, and as long as they exist for each char in the input field, it will pass true, otherwise pass false.

```
function isChar(value) {
    //Trying to create a regex that allows only Letters, Numbers, and the following special characters    @ . - ( ) # _   

    if (!value.toString().match(/@.-()#_$/)) {              
        return false;
    } return true;
}
```

Comment: `.match(/[A-z0-9@.\-()#_$]/)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're actually passing a character (you don't show how this is called), this should work:

```js
function isChar(value) {
  if (!value.toString().match(/[a-z0-9@.\-()#_\$]/i)) {
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}

console.log(isChar('%'));   // false
console.log(isChar('$'));   // true
console.log(isChar('a'));   // true
```

If instead you're passing a string, and wanting to know if *all* the characters in the string are in this "special" list, you'll want this:

```js
function isChar(value) {
  if (! value.match(/^[a-z0-9@.\-()#_\$]*$/i)) {
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}

console.log(isChar("%$_")); // false
console.log(isChar("a$_")); // true
```

Comment: The requirement is *"Trying to create a regex that allows only Letters, Numbers, and the following special characters"*

Comment: Thanks. Updated accordingly. I was going off the question itself, skipped past the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Characters that have meaning in regexp need to be escaped with `\`. So for example you would replace `$` with `\$` and so on for the other such characters. So the final regexp would look like:

```
@.\-()#_\$
```

Since you need to escape both the `-` and the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The \w class will catch the alpha numeric. The rest you provided (but properly escaped):

```
function isChar(value) {
  return value.toString().match(/[\w@.\-()#_\$]/) ? true : false
}
```